# Extend footer to fill bottom of page past the margins of the container? (left to right or width)

Tags: css

Here is my template i would like to fill the footer like on this website kars4kids.com (scroll down to the footer)

```css
.footer {
  padding: 180px 0;
  background-color: #222222;
  width:100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<footer>` tag is inside the `.container`. Kindly get it out of the wrapper, or change it to fluid container.

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">               <!-- This is the reason -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
```

Or change it to `container-fluid`.

Comment: so this is my code <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>  and this is the css .footer {
 padding: 180px 0;
 background-color: #222222;
 width:100%;
} What do I change or how do I remove it from the container? so I just insert its under the /div> tag where the container ends?

Comment: @GiovanniChavez Yes buddy.

Comment: so this is my code <div class="footer"> <p>Footer</p> and this is the css .footer { padding: 180px 0; background-color: #222222; width:100%; } What do I change or how do I remove it from the container? so I just insert its under the /div> tag where the container ends?

Comment: Change `container` to `container-fluid`.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to make the outer element (footer) to take up the full width and have another element inside to hold your content and format it correctly in the middle.

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
     <!-- content -->
  </div>
</footer>

footer {
  background: #E5F4FE;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

footer .container{
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

I've created an example here http://codepen.io/AVDW/pen/xVgLyO